# Help deriving simple equation in two dimensional collision - conservation of momentum

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, momentum, conservation-laws, collision

I need help deriving this equation using the two given expressions in a two dimensional collision problem which uses the principle of conservation of momentum in the x and y axis. Mass $m_1$ and $m_2$ are equal to m. Don't know if it helps but the expression for $\tan \theta_2= v_1' \sin \theta_1/(v_1' \cos \theta_1-v_1)$
Below is the diagram for the problem. This derivation is part of the solution and evaluation of this problem.
[image]

> Given that $$m_1v_1=m_1 v'\cos\theta_1+m_2v_2'\cos\theta_2$$ and $$0=m_1v_1\sin\theta_1+m_2v_2'\sin\theta_2$$ show that $$mv_2v_2'\cos(\theta_1-\theta_2)=0$$

Comment: Can you add a diagram with the angles and masses labelled?

Comment: Answer posted.  However, your question contains some typos in the equations and lacks sufficient background information, so it is difficult to answer with certainty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$v_1$ and $v_2$ are the velocity magnitudes of masses $m_1$ and $m_2$ respectively before the collision, while $v_1'$ and $v_2'$ are the velocity magnitudes after the collision.  One object comes in and hits the other.  Assume the first object comes in along the x axis (we are free to choose).  After the collision, $m_1$ moves off at an angle $\theta_1$ to the x axis and $m_2$ moves off at an angle $\theta_2$.

We are told that conservation of momentum implies:

$$m_1 v_1 = m_1 v_1' \cos{\theta_1}+m_2 v_2' \cos{\theta_2}$$
and
$$0 = m_1 v_1' \sin{\theta_1} + m_2 v_2' \sin{\theta_2}$$

One possibility is that the second object is initially at rest ($v_2 = 0$).  I will assume this. If so, that implies that if $\theta_1$ is positive (negative), $\theta_2$ is negative (positive).

We are also told that $m_1 = m_2 = m$, so dividing through by $m$ gives:

$$v_1 = v_1' \cos{\theta_1}+ v_2' \cos{\theta_2}$$
and
$$0 = v_1' \sin{\theta_1} + v_2' \sin{\theta_2}$$

Squaring both equations gives:

$$v_1^2 = v_1'^2 \cos^2{\theta_1}+ v_2'^2 \cos^2{\theta_2}
+ 2v_1'v_2'\cos{\theta_1}\cos{\theta_2}$$
and
$$0 = v_1'^2 \sin^2{\theta_1} + v_2'^2 \sin^2{\theta_2}
+ 2v_1'v_2'\sin{\theta_1}\sin{\theta_2}$$

Adding the first equation to the second, and making use of the trigonometric identity $\cos\theta_1\cos\theta_2 + \sin\theta_1\sin\theta_2 = \cos(\theta_1 - \theta_2)$:

$$v_1^2 = v_1'^2(sin^2\theta_1 + \cos^2\theta_1) 
+ v_2'^2(sin^2\theta_2 + \cos^2\theta_2)
+ 2v_1'v_2'(\cos\theta_1\cos\theta_1 + \sin\theta_1\sin\theta_2)
=v_1'^2 + v_2'^2 +2 v_1' v_2' \cos(\theta_1-\theta_2)$$

Finally multiply through by $\tfrac{1}{2}m$:

$$\tfrac{1}{2}mv_1^2 = 
\tfrac{1}{2}mv_1'^2 + \tfrac{1}{2}mv_2'^2 +mv_1' v_2' \cos(\theta_1-\theta_2)$$

Notice that the last term on the right is the expression you are trying to prove equal to zero.

If kinetic energy is preserved in the collision -- that is if the collision is perfectly elastic -- then by the definition of kinetic energy

$$\tfrac{1}{2}mv_1^2 = 
\tfrac{1}{2}mv_1'^2 + \tfrac{1}{2}mv_2'^2$$

In that case, and only in that case, it must be that $mv_1' v_2' \cos(\theta_1-\theta_2) = 0$, because $\tfrac{1}{2}mv_1^2$ can't equal two different things.

If the collision is not elastic, I can't see how to prove the result because, in fact, the result doesn't hold in that case.