# In this conservation of momentum problem, where is the sign error coming from?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, vectors, velocity, collision, speed

Say I have a particle travelling in the $x$-direction and breaking into two pieces:

[image]

Conservation of momentum in the $x$-direction obviously gives:

$$mv = m_1 v_1 \cos(30) + m_2 v_2 \cos(60).\tag{1}$$

In the $y$-direction, I could write the following:

$$0 = m_1 v_1 \sin(30) + m_2 v_2 \sin(60).\tag{2}$$

Or I could write:
$$ m_1 v_1 \sin(30) = m_2 v_2 \sin(60).\tag{3}$$

The two expressions in the $y$-direction obviously differ by a negative sign. Which is the correct expression?

Intuitively I'd have thought the first expression is the right one - after all it treats the two velocities $v_1$ and $v_2$ as vectors, which seems more accurate. However, working through the math it seems the second expression is the right one (or conservation of energy is violated). I'm hard-pressed to explain why before doing the math, however. Can anyone explain why the first expression is wrong and/or where the sign error is coming from?

Related: [Help deriving simple equation in two dimensional collision - conservation of momentum](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/612286/) which suggests that the first expression is correct, but it's hard to believe, since it violates conservation of energy.

Comment: In short: the second particle breaks away at an angle of $(-60^{\circ})$ instead of $(+60^{\circ})$, since you use the x-axis as reference.  Thus, $\sin (-60^{\circ}) = - \sin ( 60^{\circ})$, while the $\cos$ equations remain unchanged by that modification.

Comment: I don't see why this counts as a homework-like question, since it's largely independent of the numbers. Voting to reopen.

Comment: @Allure It's literally a "check-my-work" question. You are asking people to figure out your sign error--a sign error that you introduced. It is also a basic kinematics question. I have no idea why so many people are jumping to answer this bad question.

Comment: @Allure *You* seem to have chosen to measure the two angles in two *different* directions of increasing angle. This does not *need* to be confusing, but the framework that *you* present makes it confusing. I do not see how an answer to this question helps anyone but *you*. I also can not understand how this question is not closed as a clear "check-my-work" question.

Comment: I'm not quite sure why you think your first expression (eq.(2)) would violate conservation of (kinetic) energy, since kinetic energy depends on the square of velocity, $E = \frac12mv^2$. The directions (signs) of the $y$-components of the resulting velocities do not matter for computing the kinetic energy, but they definitely do matter for computing the momenta...

Comment: @printf you need to finish the math - you get $mv = m_2 v_2$, which suggests that particle 1 has zero mass, which is impossible unless energy conservation is violated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have a choice of you keeping track of the vertical direction, or the math keeping track.

Since you know one particle is going "up" and one particle is going "down", you can set the magnitude of their vertical momentum equal to each other.   That's what you've done with the final equation.   That works because you calculate the magnitude with the angle from horizontal.

To have the math keep track, you need to use the absolute angle.   In that case piece2 does not move at an angle of 60 degrees, but an angle of 300 degrees.  The sine of that angle is negative.

Comment: "an angle of 300 degrees" - Or, equivalently but perhaps more intuitively understandable for some, an angle of -60 degrees.

Answer (score 5):

Let the upward y-direction be $\hat y$

$$0 = m_1 v_1 \sin(30) + m_2 v_2 \sin(60).\tag{2}$$
should be written as a vector equation
$$0 \,\hat y = m_1 v_1 \sin(30)\,\hat y + m_2 v_2 \sin(60).\tag{2a} \,(-\hat y)$$

and then
$$ m_1 v_1 \sin(30) = m_2 v_2 \sin(60).\tag{3}$$

follows with component in the $(+\hat y)$ direction, $m_1 v_1 \sin(30)$, being equal to the component in the $(-\hat y)$ direction, $m_2 v_2 \sin(60)$.

Answer (score 2):

The angle you have stated is 60° is really -60° or 300° and $-sin(60) = sin(300)$

Remember the right hand rule. With thumb up, the direction of increasing angle goes with the curl of your fingers.